# How can you lower the speed of voice vibrato?

Tags: voice, vibrato

Over time with practise and good technique, I have finally developed a soft vibrato on the deeper notes. However, it is quite a fast-paced vibrato with a short period between oscillations.

What kinds of drills can I practise to increase the period between oscillations, or in other words slow down the vibrato? I am looking for a slow and rich vibrato like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-yep960vio) @ 2:30.

Comment: Hard to say for sure without hearing your voice specifically, but often too-fast vibrato is caused by air pressure beneath, instead of only through, the vocal chords. This can be an indication of poor, "tense" technique (again, not saying this is your case necessarily). If this is the case, you need to relax your entire throat and, even more importantly, your diaphragm. Start with a full breath, and keep your diaphragm relaxed, flexible, and as low as  possible. Don't "push" to create vibrato; it should naturally happen on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the video it sounds like the singer is slowing down the vibrato by singing the two notes separately and "melding" them together through *glissandos*. For me, the easiest way to sing with a slow vibrato is to do the same. I would consider the two notes as separate, and alternate between them in a smooth fashion.

For the strong and rich vibrato, you could sing the vibrato as you've practiced normally and then, with that same tone, slow it down using the method above.

Hope this helps!